# Angular js Enter keypressed to go to next page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Angular JS, I am currently attempting to make a hybrid web app. I need to use some sort of key pressing function in which when i click enter on an input tag it goes to the next page.So far i have this below:

```
 <label class="item item-input" style="width: 80%; margin:0 auto;">
    <input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name"> </input>
  </label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ng-keypress` directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress

So on your `input`, add `ng-keypress="redirectMe($event)"`

In your controller,

```
$scope.redirectMe = function(evt){
    if (evt.which === 13) {  $location.path( "/yournextpage" );  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive

HTML:

```
<button ng-enter="doAction(namePage)" ></button>
```

Github repository https://gist.github.com/EpokK/5884263